# Drawback of Multi Level Encryption

Tags: encryption, key-management, backup, luks

I am backing up my files to a RAID mirrored HDD, that has full disk encryption (FDE) in place with LUKS. Until now I did this with rsync, but I recently switched to a new backup program that does file level encryption as well.

So my question is: Is there any drawback of having multi levels of encryption, or is it actually an advantage? A drawback I can maybe think of would be managing two keys and forgetting one of them would potentially make my backup completely useless.

*EDIT*
Due to a follow-up question it's probably important to mention that I am going to use restic as the aforementioned back up application.

Comment: Performance / speed of RW

Comment: Sometimes different "levels" of encryption are designed to mitigate particular threat models.  For instance FDE is typically useless if the computer is unlocked, so provides no protection against, say, malware,

Comment: @johndoe I agree that this can be a concern. One question though: With aes-ni in the CPUs and several other performance enhancements, would you say that this  a _noticable_ problem on modern PCs?

Answer (score 3):

From a security perspective, it's an advantage. From a management perspective, you have to weigh how much extra effort it might be. If you're worried about losing keys in general, having two (or ten) probably won't change that risk. Some thought into effective key management will pay dividends. If it's not a bother, I'd go for it.

Super-encryption significantly reduces that chance that an attacker will gain access vs single encryption. They would have to exploit vulnerabilities in both encryption methods, instead of just one, which also reduces 'crimes of opportunity' if a vulnerability becomes known for one of those methods. This only works if using two different encryption methods - using the same one twice might be more or less equivalent to using a larger key.

See the Rule of Two: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_encryption

Answer (score 2):

There are no inherent advantages or drawbacks of using multiple levels of encryption. It may help depending on your threat assessment or it may breed a false sense of increased security.

Have you deliberately chosen to encrypt data using the backup program? Why? Answer this question and you'll probably get a better idea of whether you have a net gain or loss of security.

Full disk encryption is great to keep data safe at rest, when the computer is turned off. While it is running and the volume is open, if the host is compromised, the data is accessible. Using file level encryption would help protect data in this event.

As you rightly pointed out, you now have to contend with the strengths and weaknesses of 2 encryption methods and you have to manage two sets of keys. This could create addition attack vectors if you are not careful. Or it could help you isolate access and make your life easier.

As with most things around information security, it depends.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I didn't choose this on purpose, but restic (updated my initial question) offers this by default. So your third paragraph is the reason why I will stick to the current scheme. Thanks @Pedro :)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that it can be a drawback. Data security consists of three main parts: Confidentiality, Integrity, and Availability. If your encryption process is so complicated that it prevents you from accessing your data when you need it, it’s not very secure.

Clearly, one layer of AES encryption is good enough for the rest of the world in virtually every security application (TLS, banking, corporate key management and encipherment, etc.) AES by itself is plenty strong enough. So there is no security benefit in the added strength unless you’ve developed a multi-layer protocol to provide something like access control, data purging by key deletion, shared ownership, etc.

If your solution gives you secure backups without causing extra risk, there’s no problem with it. But I would never recommend implementing double encryption for the purpose of strengthening AES - whatever your threat model looks like, attacking AES isn’t a realistic weakness. (Excluding intentional CPU wasters like PBKDF2, bcrypt, Bitcoin mining, etc.; these solve a different class of problems that is unrelated to cryptographic strength.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional thought. I didn't consider double encryption to strengthen AES, but it's good to know!